# remove word to left and right of character

Tags: sql-server-2008

Using MS SQL 2008, I need to remove email addresses contained within a string of text. i.e.:

"This is a sample line of text with multiple email addresses like fred@example.com or I could also have bert@home.co.uk or even someone@somewhere.pl to mix things up".

The desired result is:

"This is a sample line of text with multiple email addresses like or I could also have or even to mix things up"

or even:

"This is a sample line of text with multiple email addresses like fred@***** or I could also have bert@***** or even someone@***** to mix things up".

There are many examples of removing everything to the left or right of a certain character, but not the removal of the text to the left or right of a fixed character up to the first space. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the string of text is within a table column you can do this in SQL Server 2008 with the help of a string spitting function and string concatenation via `for xml`.  Within newer versions of SQL Server - which you should really try to migrate towards - this is made easier with functions like `string_agg` instead of the `stuff( ... for xml )` combo.

This implentation is greedy in that it will mask any combination of characters between two spaces (or the start/end of the string) that include at least one `@` character.  So `fullsentences-like^this'one%will£be$included,so\long)as/there>is.a=@*character&somewhere` as well as strings made up of just one or more `@` character.

I'll leave how to deal with strings that *aren't* email addresses up to you.

## Query

```
with t as
(
    select *
    from(values('This is a sample line of text with multiple email addresses like fred@example.com or I could also have bert@home.co.uk or even someone@somewhere.pl to mix things up')
              ,('This is another sample line of text with multiple email addresses like fred2@example2.com or I could also have bert2@home2.co.uk or even someone2@somewhere2.pl to mix things up')
              ,('fullsentences-like^this''one%will£be$included,so\long)as/there>is.a=@*character&somewhere')
              ,('@')
              ,('a @@@@@ b')
              ,('@ @ @ @ @')
              ,('Let''s meet @ the beach')
        ) as s(s)
)
,s as
(
    select t.s
          ,s.rn
          ,case when charindex('@',s.item) > 0 then '***' else s.item end as item
    from t
        cross apply dbo.fn_StringSplit4k(t.s,' ',null) as s
)
select t.s
      ,stuff((select ' ' + s.item
              from s
              where t.s = s.s
              order by s.rn
              for xml path('')
             )
            ,1,1,''
            ) as s
from t;
```

---

## Output

| s | s |
| --- | --- |
| This is a sample line of text with multiple email addresses like fred@example.com or I could also have bert@home.co.uk or even someone@somewhere.pl to mix things up | This is a sample line of text with multiple email addresses like *** or I could also have *** or even *** to mix things up |
| This is another sample line of text with multiple email addresses like fred2@example2.com or I could also have bert2@home2.co.uk or even someone2@somewhere2.pl to mix things up | This is another sample line of text with multiple email addresses like *** or I could also have *** or even *** to mix things up |
| fullsentences-like^this'one%will£be$included,so\long)as/there>is.a=@*character&somewhere | *** |
| @ | *** |
| a @@@@@ b | a *** b |
| @ @ @ @ @ | *** *** *** *** *** |
| Let's meet @ the beach | Let's meet *** the beach |

---

## String Splitting Function

```
create function [dbo].[fn_StringSplit4k]
(
     @str nvarchar(4000) = ' '              -- String to split.
    ,@delimiter as nvarchar(1) = ','        -- Delimiting value to split on.
    ,@num as int = null                     -- Which value to return.
)
returns table
as
return
                    -- Start tally table with 10 rows.
    with n(n)   as (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1)

                    -- Select the same number of rows as characters in @str as incremental row numbers.
                    -- Cross joins increase exponentially to a max possible 10,000 rows to cover largest @str length.
        ,t(t)   as (select top (select len(isnull(@str,'')) a) row_number() over (order by (select null)) from n n1,n n2,n n3,n n4)

                    -- Return the position of every value that follows the specified delimiter.
        ,s(s)   as (select 1 union all select t+1 from t where substring(isnull(@str,''),t,1) = @delimiter)

                    -- Return the start and length of every value, to use in the SUBSTRING function.
                    -- ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the last value where there is no delimiter at the end of the string.
        ,l(s,l) as (select s,isnull(nullif(charindex(@delimiter,isnull(@str,''),s),0)-s,4000) from s)
    
    select rn
          ,item
    from(select row_number() over(order by s) as rn
               ,substring(@str,s,l) as item
        from l
        ) a
    where rn = @num
       or @num is null;
```